# SBAdmin 2 Navbar color changing

Tags: css, navbar

I could change the sidebar color of [SBAdmin2](https://startbootstrap.com/theme/sb-admin-2) as follow :

original

```
<!-- Sidebar -->
<ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar">
```

changed

```
<!-- Sidebar -->
<ul class="navbar-nav bg-info sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar">
```

But I need to change the bg-info into darkgreen or other color. Where should I change that? Been trying to change in sb-admin-2.css to #FF1493 // deep pink, it does not work:

```
    .bg-success {
  background-color: #FF1493 !important;
}
```

Advise, please

Answer (score 1):

You are changing .bg-success that's why it is not working.
Change .bg-info class instead

```
.bg-info {
    background-color: #FF1493!important;
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for that. I did change either .bg-info and .bg-success and later deploy it in navbar-nav right after. But still remain the previous color.